# С++ Генератор паролей: реализация

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Никак не получается создать генератор паролей. Каким образом можно сгенерировать пароль, состоящий из N>5 символов латинского алфавита (A-Z)? Кто может, подскажите, пожалуйста.
Требования к паролю:

1. больше 5 символов,
2. пароль должен состоять только из прописных латинских букв: A-Z.
   Благодарю заранее:)

Comment: какие-то конкретные условия генерации есть? Или просто сгенерировать набор букв?

Answer (score 1):

```
string pass;
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) pass = pass + char('A'+ rand()%26);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример программы для генерации пароля:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
int N;
const int MAX_SIZE = 128;
char str[MAX_SIZE];
srand(time(0));

do {
    system("cls");
    cout << "Введите размер пароля для генерациии (N > 5): ";
    cin >> N;
} while (N <= 5 || N >= MAX_SIZE);

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    str[i] = char('A' + rand() % 26);
str[N] = '\0';

cout << "Сгенерированный пароль: " << str << endl;
```